# Hosting a web page in SharePoint 2010 located on another application server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to host a web page in SharePoint 2010 which is located on another app server. I am trying to find a simplest way of doing this and searching gives me mostly the hints around SharePoint web parts. Is there a starndard or third party web part that will play a host for my content stored outside of SharePoint or I need to create one myself?

Comment: What's wrong with using the "page viewer web part"?

Comment: I agree you should use the page viewer web part.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed, I should have gone more thoroughly through the available web parts list instead of posting.